# Keystore location (Linux)

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I created a keystore and a certificate on my ubuntu server with the following command:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias tomcatCert -keyalg RSA
```

Now i can't find the certificate's directory. I created it as root, so it isn't in the home directory.
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the keystore to which you're saving the key. (See the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1751/ghlgv/index.html).) You could create a new keystore, or use the Java one in *[java]*/jre/lib/security.

From Oracle:

keytool -genkey -alias keyAlias -keyalg RSA -keypass changeit -storepass changeit -keystore keystore.jks

The default password is "changeit" -- simplest to keep this for development.

As an aside, it's probably best to avoid doing this (or much else) as root anyway. Use sudo if you can.